# How to access a resource as "File"

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a few files as resources in the android app.

On the other hand I have some methods that require a "File" object as an argument.

How can I bridge the two?

**Edit: I need some way to have a "File" object and not to read the file as an inputstream. thank you!**

Comment: where are these file  in raw ? or asset?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the file to external storage (reading from your raw resource's `InputStream` and writing to a new file) and then open it as a `File` from there. That's kludgy, but I'm pretty sure there's no way to get the resource as a `File` directly.