# How to access image path?

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to upload photo to Flickr, but this code is throwing an exception of file not found.The image is in the folder, but I don't know why Android is throwing an exception. Please help.

```
OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST,
        "http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/");
service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
entity.addPart("photo", new FileBody(new File("/test/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png"),
        "image/png"));
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    entity.writeTo(out);
    request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
    request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(),
            entity.getContentType().getValue());

    Response response = request.send();
    String body = response.getBody();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access files located in `drawable` folder by their absolute path.

Instead try moving the picture in the `/assets` folder and access it by `getAssets()` or move it in `/res/raw` and access it by `R.raw.icon`.

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Try opening your file with [`openRawResource(int id)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29):

> Open a data stream for reading a raw resource. This can only be used with resources whose value is the name of an asset files -- that is, it can be used to open drawable, sound, and raw resources; it will fail on string and color resources.

I think [`FileBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/FileBody.html) constructors don't accept an `InputStream`, so you'd likely need other methods to send the binary data (the file).