# How to chose which file to copy?

Tags: java, android, string, copy

I got this code to copy file from App directory to folder on SD card and use that file to set as ringtone.
But there is something that I don't understand.
How can I determine which file to take?
Let's assume I have 1 file named fusrodah in raw folder.
How can I make my app to pick that file and copy it to sdcard folder?

```
private int size;

private static final int BUFFER_LEN = 1024;


private void copyFile(AssetManager assetManager, String fileName, File out) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    size = 0;
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
    InputStream is = assetManager.open(fileName);       
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
     while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LEN)) >= 0) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            size += read;
      }
    fos.flush();    
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}
public void onClick(View arg0) {        
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/";

    File out = new File(path + "/", "fusrodah.mp3");     
    if(!out.exists()){
        try {
            copyFile(assetManager, "fusrodah.mp3", out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this

```
InputStream is = assetManager.open(fileName);
```

with

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fusrodah);
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android