# How to load properties file which is in assets folder?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android application and I need to read my properties in assets folder in `/app/src/main/assets/app.properties`.

But when I use:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
properties.load(new FileInputStream("app.properties"));
} catch (IOException e) {
...
}
```

The inputStream seems to be `null`. I think I have to precise the `filepath` or something like that to access to my properties file.

I need to use my properties in this class: `/app/src/main/java/mypackage/model/myclass.java`

Comment: follow this url http://javaant.com/how-to-use-properties-file-in-android/#.Vw4PbkfJrIU

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android/4082182#4082182 can be of some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the propertiy file using your android context like this :

```
context.getAssets().open("app.properties");
```

For example in a Fragment :

```
try{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(this.getActivity().getAssets().open("app.properties"));
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

As you seem to need this in a class where the context is not accessible you can create your own application class with a static access to the context and then use this context everywhere.

Create your application class :

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp instance;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance.getApplicationContext()
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Add your new created application into the manifest :

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.yourapp.MyApp"
    ...
```

Once this done you can load your properties in your XMLParser  :

```
try{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(MyApp.getContext().getAssets().open("app.properties"));
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I can't use getActivity().getAssets().... because i'm in a class which is not an Activity, And i can't use context.
My class is an XMLParser and my properties file stores all XML nodes i can find in my XML file.

Comment: See my updated answer to acces the context into your parser.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! it works, i didnt know that we can create a "virtual context" and that's exactly what i needed.

Comment: @Nirekin why not set `instance = this` in constructor of the application class?

Answer (score 1):

Try getting the asset and them reading it:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(fileName);
FileInputStream stream = fileDescriptor.createInputStream();
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
properties.load(stream);
} catch (IOException e) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my unit tests "XMLParserTest" in /app/src/test/java/mypackage/XMLParserTest I tried with:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    Properties prop = null;
    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/...fullpath.../app/src/main/assets/app.properties"));
        prop.load(is);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it works but when i put it in my XMLParser class my inputStream "is" is null.
It is like the class can't access to the file .properties. It works for tests only...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library: https://github.com/fernandodev/android-properties