# Reading a plain text file

Tags: java, android, file, load, bufferedreader

I know this topic probably has been covered before but I cant find an answer to the my problem.
I have a file that contains some words I need to read.
It works normally on my desktop version, but wen I try to run on an emulator, I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException - no file found`.
I understand I have to load the file in a different way than the desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code for reading the file.

```
    String line;

        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
            if (!br.ready()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                words.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

but that doesn't work on Android!!

STILL NO SOLUTION!!

Comment: "but that doesn't work on Android!!" -- that is because `words.txt` is an invalid path. Where exactly is this file?

Comment: in my assests folder.. i also tried "assests/words.txt" and  "/assests/words.txt"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach a file from context in android.

```
Context Context;
AssetManager mngr = context.getAssets();
String line;
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(mngr.open("words.txt")));
            if (!br.ready()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                words.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Or try this:

```
String line;
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("words.txt")));
            if (!br.ready()) {
                throw new IOException();
            }
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                words.add(line);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

Comment: context = cannot resolve symbol?? what am i doing wrong

Comment: also verify your asset folder in correct dir: `app/src/main/assets/`

Comment: assests are in android assests folder with the rest of the assets.. using libgdx

Answer (score 1):

Assets are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device.

To get an `InputStream` on an asset, [use `open()` on an `AssetManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)). You can get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on your `Activity`, `Service`, or other `Context`.