# Reading txt files in android... File not found

Tags: java, android, file, load, bufferedreader

This is the second thread that I have started for the same question since I did not get a right answer/working answer for my earlier question. I am trying to read a text file from my assests folder. The code works on the desktop but does not on Android. I understand I need a context or an asset manager but then I cannot get resolve method. I have tried everything so far, but I am unable to find a tutorial that works. I even changed the java version to 1.7 to get the try with resources. I am still a noob, so any help would be great. Here is the full class of reading the file and generating a word.

```
public class WordGenerator {

public String randomWord;
public Random rand;
public char [] randomWordChar;


public ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

private Context mCtx; //<-- declare a Context reference

public void WordGenerator() {


    rand = new Random();

    String all = new String("words.txt");
    String line;


    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(("words.txt")));
        if (!br.ready()) {
            throw new IOException();
        }
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            words.add(line);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
        int size = words.size();
        Random rn = new Random();
        int randWord = rn.nextInt(size);
        randomWord = words.get(randWord);
        randomWordChar = randomWord.toCharArray();
    }

}
```

I even had a couple of tries of separating the load process into a different void class but failed. If possible help thank you. Here is the link to the other question so u know the answers that did not work!!

[Reading a plain text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228980/reading-a-plain-text-file)

Comment: Have you tried doing something like this **br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("words.txt")));** ??

Comment: yes but for some reason i cant get the getAssests to work.. it always returns an error cannot resolve symbol..   so does context.getAsssests  assetmanager.getAssests same result

Comment: Can you please just post the package of the Context you are using?

Comment: import javax.naming.Context;

Comment: Yes.. Is your package of Context is **android.content.Context**? I cannot see any other reason for not resolving the **getAssets()** method unless using Context from any other thirdparty packages.

Comment: This answers your issue. You should use **android.content.Context** to get the "getAssets()" method working

Comment: thank you .. quick question do i move the whole project to the android src  package or just this class?? can i call on a class from the android package to the core package?? also please post and answer so i can mark it..

Comment: I could not get your question properly. I suppose your classfiles and resources are residing under src folder of Android project.

Comment: no my whole project is under core/src but i have a desktop and android.. i am using libgdx.. will try to move only this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **android.content.Context** to get the "getAssets()" method working.

Observed you are using **javax.naming.Context**  for the context.

Comment: also would be a great help if u know the code to use now that i can use getAsset... thank you

Comment: Check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets. This might help u