# Android Studio reading local file using emulator

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm attempting to read an audio file using:

```
File audio = new File("src/test/resources/test.flac");
```

But I'm a bit confused whether or not I can do this when debugging using an emulator.  If you can, when you do the above, what exactly is the root/relative folder?

I'm currently debugging using the emulator on Windows and I have made sure that the file is in the test/resources directory, but using:

```
if(audio.exists())
```

Always returns false.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you try to read a file then you know where the file resides. So use an absolute path.

Comment: It would help if you added the OS you are using. Also, any information relative to the project, emulator and android studio installation and directory structure would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access resource files in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081763/access-resource-files-in-android)

Comment: When the code is compiled, the `src/` directory no longer exists. To put files in your app, you need to use an Assets folder